# Javascript array element refers to other element

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object which describes the radius of a hemisphere and the volume. I'd like to be able to change the radius and then access the volume with `hemisphere.volume` and it would return the volume for the current radius. I thought something like this would be possible but I'm getting `NaN` back from it when I call `hemisphere.volume` from the console.

```
var hemisphere ={radius:6,volume:Math.pow(this.radius,3)*4*Math.PI/6};
```

Then I thought I could do this as a function like:

```
var hemisphere ={radius:6,volume:function({Math.pow(this.radius,3)*4*Math.PI/6}};
```

This gives me 'undefined' when I call `problem.answer()` from the console.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: You need to learn some JavaScript basics, like how to write a function and return values from it.

Comment: Using a function is the appropriate solution, you just need to use valid syntax and not forget the `return` keyword: `volume:function()
 { return Math.pow(this.radius,3)*4*Math.PI/6; }`